# Why my Log File is Not Been Created In The Local Explorer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, logging, log4j2

I only want to log my Exceptions which I get at the time of Run Time. I have An Application_Logger.class, Application.properties,log4j2. properties file. and of course the main class. Can anyone help me creating a log file?

App_Logger.Class

```
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

    import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

    public class ApplicationLogger {
    transient static Logger cat = (Logger) LogManager.getLogger(ApplicationLogger.class);
    public static final boolean TRACE_EMPTY_EXCEPTION_CALL = true;
    /**
     *  Logs the message
     */
    public static void log(String message){
        cat.debug(message);
    }

    public static void log(String message, UserDTO loginUser) {
        cat.debug(getLoginUserDetails(loginUser) + message);
    }

    /**
     * Logs the message and the exception
     */
    public static void log(String message, Exception e){
        log(message, e, null);
    }

    public static void log(String message, Exception e, UserDTO loginUser) {
        if(e != null)
            cat.error(getLoginUserDetails(loginUser) + message, e);
        else {
            if(TRACE_EMPTY_EXCEPTION_CALL) {
                try {
                    throw new Exception("Empty exception encountered");
                }catch(Exception ex) {
                    log(message, ex, loginUser);
                }
            }
            else
                cat.debug(getLoginUserDetails(loginUser) + message);
        }
    }
    /** logs the message as an error
     * 
     * @param message
     */
    public static void logError(String message){
        logError(message, null);
    }

    public static void logError(String message, UserDTO loginUser){
        cat.error(getLoginUserDetails(loginUser) + message);
    }

    public static void log(String empNo, String operation, String operand){
        cat.debug(empNo + ":" + operation + ":" + operand);
    }

    public static String getLoginUserDetails(UserDTO loginUser) {
        if(loginUser == null)
            return "";
        return "[" + loginUser.getEmpId() + ", " + loginUser.getTenantId() + "] ";
    }
    }
```

Application.properties File

```
    log4j2.debug=true
```

InitApplication.class

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3000")
    public class InitApplication implements CommandLineRunner{
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
    SpringApplication.run(InitApplication.class, args);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just an error in pom.xml file.

Earlier it was like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
<artifactId>ABC</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>ABC</name>
<description>LOG4j2</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>

</dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
            
    <dependency>
               <groupId>org.json</groupId>
               <artifactId>json</artifactId>
               <version>20180813</version>
     </dependency>
     
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
            
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>   
     
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Then I added these lines, basically, I excluded Spring boot default starter logger and added log4j2 logger by adding its dependencies.
Like This.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```